# Webpack . command is failing

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking into creating a project that has server and client folders. In my client folder I wanted to create a react app, but without using create-react-app, because I wanted to have full control of what being installed as well as understand better how things work. For this I followed this [article](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-create-a-react-app-without-using-create-react-app-c004a62b52fc). However, at the stage of running build command:

```
"build": "Webpack ."
```

I got error:

```
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.' in '/Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client'
resolve '.' in '/Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client'
  using description file: /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    No description file found in /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project or above
    no extension
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client is not a file
    .js
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client.js doesn't exist
    .tsx
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client.tsx doesn't exist
    .json
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client.json doesn't exist
    .ts
      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client.ts doesn't exist
    as directory
 existing directory /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client
        using description file: /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/package.json (relative path: .)
          using path: /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/index
            using description file: /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/package.json (relative path: ./index)
              no extension
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/index doesn't exist
              .js
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/index.js doesn't exist
              .tsx
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/index.tsx doesn't exist
              .json
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/index.json doesn't exist
              .ts
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client/index.ts doesn't exist
```

I can only suspect that issue is because I have two folder in my main folder:

```
Project/client
Project/server
```

My webpack file located in `Project/client/webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    port: "3333",
    static: ["./public"],
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".tsx", ".json", ".ts"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node-modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server .",
    "build": "Webpack ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

I have my `.js` files located in `src` folder.
`App.js`:

```
const App = () => {
  return <div>WORKING!</div>;
};

export default App;
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Folder structure:
[image]

Can you help me understand what my command is missing?

UPDATE:
After I changed my build command, as suggested by Pratik Wadekar, build ran successfully, but after I ran `npm start` page still opened with error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.' in '/Users/al/Documents/Project/Accounting/client'
```

Comment: Try running only `"build":"webpack"`

Comment: Pratik Wadekar, it did run successfully... what happened?

Comment: but when I ran afterwards `npm start` browser opened with error: 
`Compiled with problems:

ERROR

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.' in '/Users/al/Documents/Development/Project/client'`
So I guess it's still failing.

Comment: `"start": "webpack serve"` should do the work

Comment: it did work. But can you expain difference between `Webpack .` and `Webpack`, `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack serve`. Why it was failing and why these commands work?

Comment: Pratik Wadekar, if you could add it as answer with explanation I would accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to run `webpack .` The dot means current working directory. But webpack always considers configuration from the directory that you are already working in. So there is no need to explicitly tell webpack that run from within this directory.

Also `webpack serve` internally uses `webpack-dev-server`. You were running `"start": "webpack-dev-server ."` it should have been this `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js"`.  `webpack-dev-server` requires a config file.